# Facebook iOS app - How to know the users that authorize my Facebook app

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, authorization

I have a Facebook app at https://developers.facebook.com that is connected to my native iOS app, and I also use the Facebook iOS SDK to extend my application with social networking capabilities.

My app will ask the user to authorize it by logging in using Facebook.

My question is how to know the users that already authorized the app so I can put them in a special list (`UITableView`)?

Comment: Why do you keep writing hordes of commas in your subject lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a list of all your app's users unless you've been keeping track of this server side.

You can get a list of a user's friends that also use your app by calling `/me/friends?fields=installed` - there'll be an 'installed:true' in the response for friends which have authorised your app